# Difference between Query keywords Containing, IsContaining, Contains, Like in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

What is the difference between Query keywords `Containing`, `IsContaining`, `Contains`, `Like` in Spring Data?

```java
List<T> findBy...Containing();
List<T> findBy...Contains();
List<T> findBy...IsContaining();
List<T> findBy...Like();
```

Answer (score 2):

`IsContaining`, `Containing` and `Contains` are almost same.

For example,

```
List<Employee> findByNameContaining(String name);
List<Employee> findByNameContains(String name);
List<Employee> findByNameIsContaining(String name);
```

For all above methods spring data will create query with `LIKE` clause where value will be wrapped in `%` as shown in below query when `Name = ABC`

```
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE Name LIKE '%ABC%'
```

Whereas in `Like` method user need to explicitly add the wildcards.

For example,

```
List<T> findByNameLike(String name);
```

For above method spring data will create query similar to below query when `Name = ABC`

```
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE Name LIKE 'ABC'
```